# Can JavaFX Node.snapshot(..) capture a ComboBox and its popup together?

Tags: javafx, popup, snapshot

I have a custom spinner that handles LocalDate values and includes a `PopupControl` that displays a calendar, similar to the `DatePicker` control. This isn't exactly the same as the problem described in the question but the two cases are analogous.

I would like to take a 'snapshot' of *both* the control and the popup while the calendar is displayed. Using the `Node.snapshot(..)` method, I'm able to capture the spinner by itself and the calendar by itself, but not both together. Note: I've tried modifying the the SnapshotParemeters parameter required by the method to provide a `viewport` value that would include both the spinner and popup, but without success.

I've also tried using the `Scene.snapshot(..)` method in an event handler for event type `WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN`. This captures the entire scene but does ..NOT.. show the popup.

As requested by @Kleopatra here is some *minimal reproducible code*:

```
public class ComboBoxController {

 @FXML
 private BorderPane rootPane;

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @FXML
 private void initialize() {

      //- initialize controls
      final VBox vbox = new VBox();
      final ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();

      //- populate containers
      rootPane.setCenter(vbox);
      vbox.getChildren().add(comboBox);

      //- make pref sizes sufficiently large to handle combo box and popup list view w/no overflow
      vbox.setPrefSize(200, 200);
      rootPane.setPrefSize(250, 250);

      //- load combo box items
      comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
      comboBox.getItems().setAll("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "black", "white");

      //- register event handler
      comboBox.setOnShown(e -> {

           //- get handle for popup list view
           final Object skin = comboBox.getSkin();
           final Node node = ((ComboBoxListViewSkin<String>) comboBox.getSkin()).getPopupContent();
           final ListView<String> popupListView = ((ListView<String>) node);

           final String path = " [enter path to appropriate location on your file system] ";
           final SnapshotParameters parameters = new SnapshotParameters();



           Stream.of(
                     new Pair<>(vbox, "vbox.png"),
                     new Pair<>(comboBox, "comboBox.png"),
                     new Pair<>(popupListView, "popupListView.png"))
                 .forEach(p -> {
                      final WritableImage image = p.getKey().snapshot(parameters, null);
                      final File file = new File(path + p.getValue());
                      try {
                           ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
                      }
                      catch (final IOException ex) {
                      }
                 });

           //- expand viewport for snapshot parameters, this should provide enough space to
           //  display popup list view ..AND.. combo box ... assuming they can both be captured in
           //  the same snapshot.
           final Bounds bounds = vbox.getBoundsInParent();
           final Rectangle2D viewport = new Rectangle2D(
                                                        bounds.getMinX(),
                                                        bounds.getMinY(),
                                                        bounds.getWidth(),
                                                        bounds.getHeight());
           parameters.setViewport(viewport);
           Stream.of(
                     new Pair<>(vbox, "vbox2.png"),
                     new Pair<>(comboBox, "comboBox2.png"),
                     new Pair<>(popupListView, "popupListView2.png"))
                 .forEach(p -> {
                      final WritableImage image = p.getKey().snapshot(parameters, null);
                      final File file = new File(path + p.getValue());
                      try {
                           ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
                      }
                      catch (final IOException ex) {
                      }
                 });
      });
 }
```

}

Is what I'm trying to do possible, and if so then what am I missing and/or doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @kleopatra - thanks for your reply, the question has been edited to include what your requested. I find this somewhat odd, and no offense intended (seriously), but it is hard to believe you haven't encountered something like this before. You're experienced, and ask good questions and give good answers. Haven't you seen this issue before?